# Filtering records based on Xpath expression

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am trying to filter worker records based on the 2 digit country code (ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code). I want to filter the records of workers working in country India(IN).

Below is the XML source code:

```
<wd:Get_Workers_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v32.0">
    <wd:Worker>
        <wd:Employment_Data>
            <wd:Home_Country_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">AR</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">ARG</wd:ID>
            </wd:Home_Country_Reference>
        </wd:Employment_Data>
        <wd:Personal_Data>
            <wd:Name_Data>
                <wd:First_Name>Rohit</wd:First_Name>
                <wd:Last_Name>Singh</wd:Last_Name>
            </wd:Name_Data>
        </wd:Personal_Data>
    </wd:Worker>
    <wd:Worker>
        <wd:Employment_Data>
            <wd:Home_Country_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">IN</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">IND</wd:ID>
            </wd:Home_Country_Reference>
        </wd:Employment_Data>
        <wd:Personal_Data>
            <wd:Name_Data>
                <wd:First_Name>Shivam</wd:First_Name>
                <wd:Last_Name>Dubey</wd:Last_Name>
            </wd:Name_Data>
        </wd:Personal_Data>
    </wd:Worker>
</wd:Get_Workers_Response>
```

I have used the below Xpath expression:

```
//wd:Employment_Data[wd:Home_Country_Reference/wd:ID = 'IN']
```

This gives me the below output:

```
Element='<wd:Employment_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
            <wd:Home_Country_Reference>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">IN</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">IND</wd:ID>
            </wd:Home_Country_Reference>
        </wd:Employment_Data>'
```

The output of this Xpath expression doesn't contain a Personal_Data node. Is it possible to filter data based on 'IN' country and have both nodes (Employment_Data and Personal_Data) in the output by using Xpath expressions? Or do we have to use XSLT for this transformation?

Expected Output:

```
<wd:Get_Workers_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v32.0">
    <wd:Employment_Data>
        <wd:Home_Country_Reference>
            <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">IN</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">IND</wd:ID>
        </wd:Home_Country_Reference>
    </wd:Employment_Data>
    <wd:Personal_Data>
        <wd:Name_Data>
            <wd:First_Name>Shivam</wd:First_Name>
            <wd:Last_Name>Dubey</wd:Last_Name>
        </wd:Name_Data>
    </wd:Personal_Data>
</wd:Worker>
</wd:Get_Workers_Response>
```

Comment: You basically need XQuery or XSLT as soon as you want to create some new result structure, pure XPath doesn't allow you to select more than existing nodes, you can't compose a new root with new or only part of the children of the input root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting the EmploymentData node. Try the following:

//wd:Worker[wd:Employment_Data/wd:Home_Country_Reference/wd:ID = 'IN']

Comment: Thanks, it is working as expected. One question though, Do I need to add the attribute 'ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code' in the Xpath expression as I am filtering records based on it ?